# Why won't this Python 3.x function not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

We just learned functions in class a couple days ago and I am not sure why this function won't run. It is basically identical to the functions that I did in class.

```
def pay(hrs, rate, finalPay):
    hrs = int(input("Hours worked"))
    rate = float(input("Pay grade"))
    finalPay = (hrs * rate)
    if hrs > 40:
        finalPay = (((finalPay - 40) * 1.5) + finalPay)
        return finalPay

print(pay)
```

I get function pay at 0x109b5a6a8 in the terminal after I try to run it. If I try to list the parameters in the print function I get a traceback error stating said parameters are not defined. I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: You're asking to print the function itself—as opposed to a value of that function. The output you're getting is the address of that function in memory.

Comment: ① either pass the arguments values or use `input(...)` ② `if hrs > 40: final_pay = ((hours-40)*1.5+40)*rate` ③ the `return` statement is not always executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't take the variables when creating that function.

```
def pay():
```

You are defining them in your function:

```
def pay():
    hrs = int(input("Hours worked"))
    rate = float(input("Pay grade"))
    finalPay = (hrs * rate)
    if hrs > 40:
        finalPay = (((finalPay - 40) * 1.5) + finalPay)
        return finalPay
```

And use the function like:

```
print(pay())
```

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the reference to the `pay` function. If you want to call the function, you need to have parenthesis (`()`):

```
print(pay())
```

Note that `hrs` and `rate` are inputted inside the function, and `finalPay` is calculated inside it, so all three should be removed from the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, what you are trying to do is print the function's address.

If you want to print the output of the function, `finalPay` you need to call the function.

To call a function you have to put `()` after it's name which contains the parameters passed to the function.

So, in this case, use `print(pay(1,2,3))` instead of just `print(pay)` where 1, 2 and 3 will be your `hrs`, `rate` and `finalPay` variables' values.

I think you don't yet know much about **functions** in programming languages. I suggest you to  [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_functions.htm) to get an overview.

Answer (score 0):

To call a function you need to add parenthesis to place where you want to call.

In your example, you need to write last line like this:

`print(pay(1, 2, 3))`